# Change field settings for text field from plain to formatted while data exists

Tags: 8, entities, input-formats

anyone know of a quick example of how to change the field settings for a text area (plain) to formatted and set the input formatter (or maybe it will use default)? Will this require a resave of all the data or can it just be changed for the entity type? I currently have a lot of existing data on this site.

The field is currently stored as the type `string`, Text (plain). I need to change it to `text_long`, Text (formatted, long).

Thanks

Comment: In Drupal 7 you could've used Helper module's FieldChangeHelper class
https://git.drupalcode.org/project/helper/blob/7.x-1.x/lib/FieldChangeHelper.php
Alas, nothing similar yet exists for Drupal 8

Answer (score 4):

Attention for Drupal 8:

You need to update at least 3 or 4 yml files

field.field.node.page.field_description.yml

```
(same change)
```

field.storage.node.field_description.yml

```
--- a/config/default/field.storage.node.field_description.yml
+++ b/config/default/field.storage.node.field_description.yml
@@ -4,13 +4,13 @@
 dependencies:
   module:
     - node
+    - text
 id: node.field_description
 field_name: field_description
 entity_type: node
-type: string_long
-settings:
-  case_sensitive: false
-module: core
+type: text_long
+settings: {  }
+module: text
 locked: false
 cardinality: 1
 translatable: true
```

core.entity_form_display.node.page.default.yml

```
-type: string_textarea 
+type: text_textarea
```

core.entity_view_display.node.page.default.yml

```
-type: basic_string
+type: text_default
```

Maybe the last 2 ones you can deal with those changes on UI(go to each teaser and save). But I did in config folder.

Comment: While this will have changed the appearance of the node form, the data will not be saved correctly, and will not be displayed correctly.

Comment: While this didn't work per se, it did work with the help of this blog article because the formatter and widget settings were hidden with that approach and this allowed me to adjust those in the YAML files, thanks @carlos  https://blog.42mate.com/change-field-type-with-existing-data-on-drupal-8/

Answer (score 1):

Oh wow, I just tried something in hopes of it being easy and it was a breeze!...

I already have all my config exported to code so I compared a `text_long` field to my current `string_long` field and just merged the differences, it worked beautifully. Something like the changes in the following example patch:

```
--- config/prod/field.field.node.page.field_description.yml (revision 3ef14eada9090087d33a10ec532732e515fef151)
+++ config/prod/field.field.node.page.field_description.yml (revision )
@@ -5,6 +5,8 @@
   config:
     - field.storage.node.field_description
     - node.type.page
+  module:
+    - text
 id: node.researcher.field_description
 field_name: field_description
 entity_type: node
@@ -16,4 +18,4 @@
 default_value: {  }
 default_value_callback: ''
 settings: {  }
-field_type: string_long
+field_type: text_long
```

imported the changed config et voila! Just beautiful.

Comment: I doubt it really just works like that. Note that the field type is also in the storage, and that changing the field type results in a different field schema, which drupal will actually prevent you from changing if you try it on the field storage config.

Comment: @Berdir of course you are correct. Guess I am still looking to solve this. Seemed good at first but then I noted the display was rendering with html markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module Druidfire by CHX.

https://gitlab.com/chx_/druidfire

Drush 10 command: `drush druidfire:string2formatted entity_type field_name`

It's not hosted on drupal.org and is unlikely to be. Use with caution.

Example update hook for your `module_name.install` file:

```
/**
 * Change field my_field to formatted text.
 */
function module_namee_update_8001() {   
  \Drupal::service('druidfire')->kaboom('string2formatted', 'node', 'field_my_field');
}
```

Comment: This seems useful, why isn't it on Drupal.org?

Comment: @Kevin See: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3079843#comment-13250398 "But note the standard "there is no warranty" clause, even more so than usual because this module bypasses the entity APIs. Even if I moved this module to drupal.org it very likely would become a sandbox because there is absolutely no way I would want to support it. "